How might a creature be so adapted to the temperature of its home planet that it can't survive on any other without protection?
I have a science fiction/fantasy/speculative story which has several sentient races (as well as humans). All of them appear human for the most part, but have some features of certain animals (tails, wings, etc.)
The Salamandrion, one of the twelve sentient species, are based off (wingless) dragons and amphibians, or so it's presumed, because very few people have ever seen them without the protective suits they must wear to survive outside Coreworld, their home planet. You see, Coreworld is extremely hot and hellish (think Mustafar from Star Wars episode 3), and the Salamandrion are so well adapted to this environment that, without protection, they will get too cold and die on a planet with normal temperatures.
My only problem is, how exactly would this work biologically? Why would they basically "freeze" in a normal 15-40 degree centigrade climate? Note that all of the sentient species are descended from humans somehow, so why haven't they adapted back already?

Having just had this discussion with another user, you probably mean "sapient." Sentient = aware of surroundings. A computer with a temperature sensor is simplistically sentient. Sapient = reasoning and the ability to think intelligently. Tarantulas and humans are both sentient, but of the two, only humans are sapient.

BTW, have you done any research into how humans self-regulate our internal temperature? (See [ask].) If all your creatures descend from human stock, then you're talking about how human physiology must change to become cold-blooded, like most lizards. (Which would make your Q a duplicate of this or this.) Aw, crap. Can you [edit] your question to specifically state you're looking for a warm-blooded solution? Or is it a duplicate of those others?

Humans won't freeze if they go without their protective suits when it's 5 °C (41 °F) outside, but they will still die of hypothermia. (And if there is some wind that won't even take very long.)

On the opposite side of the spectrum, ice worms are so adapted to cold that they melt above 40 degrees F. I'll have to see if I can find anything similar for thermophiles.

Even in our very own world, most species are adapted to a relatively narrow range of temperatures. It depends a bit on whether by "hot and hellish" you mean Venus or Louisiana (both of which deserve the label), but isn't what you're asking for the norm rather than the exception?

Very few insert-name-here ever saw humans naked in a normal, -25°C - 0°C environment. Not even humans regularly see other humans in such conditions naked (except of Finns). When venturing to a 0°C, humans wear protective suits. Without such protection, they get too cold and die. They freeze to death (technically, die first, and then freeze). What's preventing you from using this system, merely shifted along temperature scale?

@Agent_L In my experience (granted, 35+ years old) even the Finns don a bathing suit at -25°C.

@JBH Sorry about missing the point between "sentient" and "sapient". I've always used "sentient" but what you're saying makes sense. I'll use "sapient" from now on.

@Yeslek71 Yeah I had something like that that in mind when designing these creatures, but the opposite.

@KeilahH: This question would be improved by specifying the range of temperatures you expect these creatures to live in on Coreworld, especially for those of us who don't know the specs of Mustafar off the top of our head.

I would think there are few humans that do not have protective suits for venturing out in merely Earthly temperatures.

@Keilah H   You wrote: "The Salamandrion, one of the twelve sentient species, are based off (wingless) dragons and amphibians,.."  In my understanding of English "based off of" and "based on" are correct but "based off" is fit only for the dialog of careless speakers.

And I agree that humans are only comfortable in a narrow range of temperatures.

M. A. Golding Sorry for the bad grammar.

Wingless Dragons (Reptile) or Amphibians, well regardless of their maturity lifecycle. You are making the point that they require higher temp. to survive. You didn't go into detail about "how they die" or "how they stay alive" only that they get too cold on a "normal planets"
You give us Mustafar as an example of a world they would prefer. (Which is good, because Mustafar is vague enough, and with real examples like Kepler-10b probably not possible to justify life)

35% lava on the surface, with 800°C lava.
Very few temperate regions remain, surrounded by basalt/obsidian mountains.
Very low amounts of water outside those regions.
Significant volcanic activity, causing updrafts and thermal currents.
Massive lightning storms and Ash-Storms
Atmosphere that is "hot and chemical" filled with black clouds, choking ash, toxic gases, noxious fumes in hazy fog.


So clearly they have an organ that keeps them cold, that works so fundamentally that it is not under conscious control. Similar to how we do not consciously control our own body temp.
This cooling method cannot be sweating, as worlds like Mustafar do not supply enough water to sustain such a cooling method. And this method would be easily circumvented. (as funny as it would be for them to literally sweat 4Litres of liquid every hour and their suits are just massive tanks of this liquid that they need to go drain every few hours...)
Most reptiles are commonly understood as "cold blooded" or Ectothermic body temperature regulation, though I think that would be "not enough" for a world like Mustafar.
If they are some kind of human-reptile-amphibian hybrid they do not need to be Ectothermic, but they are very likely to be a Poikilotherm in the sense that they can endure massive internal temp. fluctuations.
I would expect that their ability to cool down directly from the environment is what you want to focus on.
Unless you are trying to go into exhaustive detail, perhaps this species naturally has a very high metal rich diet that allows them to grow metallic scales and bones that extend out of the skin. You'll have to go higher than "hummingbirds" on the internal temp scale here, but if they have a body temp of say 70°C and you "handwavium" the issues away with "organic-metallic cells" and "high metal diet"
The metallic scales would reflect most of the thermal energy of the starlight they receive and helps reflect infrared energy away from them. (Think of IR-pictures or mirrors that are used to heat inside houses)

With this "scales and bones" as an "organ", this species would prevent most atmospheric heat sources from affecting them.
I would submit that the talons used at the bottom of their feet/hands are the only "nonmetalic" external material because they are insulators between the actively melting ground and their body (think of reptiles in deserts that walk around on "tip toe")
The external "bones" that connect directly to internal metallic bone structures would allow a member of this species to take advantage of technology and literally use "cooling devices" to directly maintain a properly low temp in region of their world that were "too hot" (perhaps this species was intentionally designed this way, so that they could endure super hot worlds with additional technology helping bridge the gap between what was possible with biogenetic engineering and what reality required)
Then you can easily say that a normal world, with temps ranging from 10-35° is literally a frozen wasteland for them, similar to how humans would feel in a clear day in winter without a jacket.
Inside their protective suits is literally just a heater directly attached to key external bone structures.
Because their internal biological processes require a higher temp to function, they will slowly "run out of energy" as their metallic blood gets thicker and thicker at lower temps until basically their circulatory system freezes solid resulting in death.

In addition if we go into the dragon aspect a little bit, a world with noxious gas and smoke clouds... perhaps this species requires exotic fumes or to breath in ash intentionally for filtering purposes. This would make going off world even more difficult, requiring stange "deadly" gases to even survive, while they wouldn't die immediately from not having them... long term deprivation of these things would negatively affect their ability to digest food or something. (Perhaps the fumes help with brain function providing trace materials used to create metallic brain cells, resulting in infants being given "fume chamber" treatments at young ages to encourage higher IQ)

I would suggest that perhaps their world has a very limited amount of water, in the form of perhaps a protected pocket of Ice within an insulating thick layer of a rock that does not exchange heat very well. (Think of oxygen not included, how there are ice pockets betside lava, but of course we don't have abyssilite with 0 conductivity)
https://www.britannica.com/science/rock-geology/Thermal-properties
Looking at the chart there, perhaps this species has good fortune and has a massive crystal home that is quartzite or quartz.

I have no idea if this idea aligns with your imagination, but I looked at real life reptiles and how they regulated body temps, thought about how dragons looked, and thought about how a designed or evolved species might look in the context of Mustafar.

Man, this is a lot, but it makes sense! Thanks!

It also would actually explain a ton of things about the species' relation to others. Unusual eating habits and the whole "exotic fumes are needed" thing would further enhance their separation from the other 11 species, and it honestly all sounds really fun to mess around with.

The metallic scales idea is particularly intriguing since among microorganisms, what tends to set obligate thermophiles (require high temperatures to survive) apart from more flexible thermophiles is that they essentially "breathe" metal rather than oxygen. I'm not sure that would work for a large multicellular lifeform, but it's mentioned here that metal-based "respiration" is much less efficient at moderate temperatures.

If a creature is going to survive in an environment, they either need a body temperature that is strictly greater than the coolest things ever-present in that environment, or else they must constantly gather and expend resources on some on-going endothermic reaction that lowers the temperature of their radiative surfaces to below their body temperature. Such endothermic reactions (for example, the evaporation of water) are generally not nearly so effective as exothermic reactions (for example, burning food), so  living in such a fashion is marginal at best.

I.e., Metal radiative scales and fins are not going to be enough for a 70C creature to survive in an environment where the ambient temperature is greater than 70C. Such fins and scales would be a conduit for external heat to enter the body instead of internal heat exiting the body. And when the body warms up to its surroundings, the creature is dead. as its bodily functions will cease to work.

@PaulSinclair even in my answer I said that you'd need to "handwavium" stuff that is impossible. I was only proposing reasonable ways, not factually possible ones, to explain what the OP was asking. I was guessing that they aren't going to be writing a scientific biological entry on the species, as the author of their world they need to know even if they don't tell us what the inside of the atmos suit does for this species. It doesn't have to be perfect, it is just a foundation for a reasonably consistent set of descriptions, actions, and effects.

Their intelligently designed hyperspatial cooling organ actively rejects heat into hyperspace using the same exotic physics that lets you have an interstellar society.
While it could be surgically removed or chemically suppressed for the first few hundred generations since the Great Human Diaspora, thousands and thousands of years of extremely aggressive genetic tinkering have resulted not only in the Salamandrions looking more like dinosaurs than primates, but also the vital integration of the hyper-cooling organ into the respiratory and digestive system which now allows them to eat volcanic ores for energy instead of relying on food grown in climate-controlled enclosed aeroponics farms.
This mighty technology was lost, along with most records, in a great Galactic Dark Age. Their myths record that they were once humans who struck a bargain with the planet's patron deity: that they shall have mighty dragon bodies, feast on delicious volcanic ores, and dance unharmed among the flames; but in return they may never again dwell in the temperate climates of their ancestors, but shall evermore be people of the sacred lava.
Modern Salamandrion biologists have re-discovered the first description. They regard the second description as a primitive superstition, while most regular Salamandrions either take the myth at face value or consider it metaphorically true, revealing important moral and theological truths. But there are a few who have studied the ancient lore more closely. They know that beneath the so-called myth is a truth more sublime and more horrifying than anyone has imagined. Don don donnnnn.

Ok, this is amazing. At first I wasn't sure if it'd make sense with my existing worldbuilding, but then I remembered that these creatures are so cut off from everyone else, that some of these concepts could hold true.

There are already creatures on Earth that can't survive at less than 80°C (or less than 100°C): the extremophile.
And it's extremely simple: their DNA will code for enzymes that can only work in some temperature ranges (like yours and the many other microbes on Earth that'll die at 40°C and stop developing under 15°C). The only difference here is that their enzymes works at 80/100°C range and if you cool them, their metabolism stops, and they die.
Biologically, the enzyme is a catalyst for a chemical reaction. Without the enzyme the reaction wouldn't take place or would be to slow or too fast. The reaction doesn't consume the enzyme, once it's done, the enzyme is available again to "help" another reaction.
How can enzyme be temperature dependent?
It's not the enzyme that is temperature dependent (*), it's the chemical compounds that changes shape & activity with the temperature.
Think temperature as a measure of molecule and atom activity (or movement). If the temperature is too low, there's not enough movement in atoms and chemical bonds won't break (or, if they do, they recombine immediately without using another molecule).
The enzyme helps that by snugging into these chemical bonds and placing the other molecule (or transporting, or ...) at the right place so when the bond is broken, it has chances to rebind to the other molecule instead.
But if the environment is too cold, the enzymes either aren't fast enough (fast = movement = temperature) to snug in, or the initial molecules haven't enough atom activity to even break their own bond by themselves.
Why wouldn't you find such enzyme everywhere ?
Storing information in DNA is a energy consuming feature and nature is made to fit the energy budget to the survival requirement. No specie would waste energy coding and replicating the code for an enzyme that's not useful in the current environment in the long term. So your "standard" humans, even if they had those enzyme in their distant path, simply dropped them since they were neither useful in a 40°C environment. The dragons, on the other side, dropped the 40°C capable enzymes since the 80° or 100°C were better suited for their environment.

Going by your sentence "Note that all of the sentient species are descended from humans somehow." The 'easiest' answer would be evolution over time.
Evolution on our earth takes years and is based on natural selection and genetic drift. Over many generations (takes time). Humans have an ideal range of temperature to live in. When a human body gets to warm or to cold we have heat-shock proteins (HSPs) or cold-shock proteins (CSPs) that try to protect our bodies from taking damage.
You present the Salamandrion as one of the twelve sentient species. That survived/evolved on their home planet  and became well adapted to this environment. Evolution made it so their internal biology works within the temperature range of their planet. Meaning compared to humans on earth their anatomy/biology is completely focused on a higher base level of temperature and has higher set boundaries for high and low temperature.
therefor I would say Evolution would already cover your question. It would take many years to get a 'natural' resistance to 15-40 degree centigrade of cold. Their organs/tissue/cells/proteins need a warmer climate to function.

Protein Folding
They do no "freeze" to death exactly.  Certain proteins change shape when they exceed a certain temperature, and when this happens the organism typically dies because it causes their cells to stop working or even to rip itself apart.
However, if these humanoids were genetically modified to function using these protein structures that form only at higher temperatures, then when cooled below a certain point, the proteins would all change shape and your would similarly die.

If I understand the setup correctly, what makes this interesting is the asymmetry. In the Star Wars film, humans could survive outside on Mustafar. If Coreworld is meant to be survivable for humans, but Earth isn't survivable for unprotected Salamandrion, then there is certainly something to explain.
But I think you have many choices. It could be as simple as their lung surfactant being chemically different so that it works great above 52 degrees C but congeals and becomes ineffective (maybe even toxic) if the incoming air is below 40 degrees. I like that one because it means their air has to be treated and they can't just wear a coat. It's no big deal that they're descended from humans; after all, whales are descended from land animals and have made huge changes. It's true that biochemistry often stays more similar, but it can definitely change if there's an evolutionary reason.
As side note, if Coreworld is actually not meant to be survivable by humans, and its temperature is above the boiling point of water, then you have to think about what kind of life could survive there at all. Our models of life assume a working fluid. It would become a whole different challenge to the imagination to make it believable.

Well, there isn't exactly a planet that's specifically Earth in this universe, but most of the other planets are basically Earths or Earth-like. And that lung surfactant idea makes sense, I might end up going with some form of that in conjunction with some of the other ideas.
